# Nuxt dynamic routes defined in module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Good time of the day,

I've encountered pretty strange issue with Nuxt@2.0 which is the following:

1. Create module and dynamically load routes
2. Navigate to page using the sidebar - page works just fine (content displayed, etc)
3. Copy page url and open it in a new tab - 404, BUT, all the meta data from the breadcrumbs generator is there (it parses the route name and creates entries for breadcrums)

So, technically, nuxt is able to load the page, however, it fails to actually load it (strange wording, but i've no idea on how to describe it better).

**Plugins used:**

1. nuxt@edge (2.0~)
2. nuxt-i18n - all routes are affixed with the `___locale` string, so, for example: `dashboard___en`, `dashboard___es`, `dashboard___ru`, etc

In order to dynamically load routes, the following `plugin` is used (defined under plugins in `nuxt.config.js`):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export default ({ app: { router } }) => {
    const routingContext = require.context('../modules', true, /.routing.js$/);

    routingContext.keys().map((file) => [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), routingContext(file)]).reduce((pluginRoutes, [name, module]) => {
        Vue.use(module, router);
    }, {});
};
```

The `routing.js` file inside the modules folder looks like this:

```
import { backendRoute, routeNameGenerator } from '~/libs/helpers';
import config from '~/config';
import forEach from 'lodash.foreach';

import CompanyPage from './pages/company';

export function install (Vue, router, options = {}) {

    let routes = [
        {
            path: backendRoute('namespace/module/company'),
            name: routeNameGenerator('namespace.module.company'),
            component: CompanyPage
        }
    ];

    let localizedRoutes = [];

    forEach(routes, (route) => {
        forEach(config.application.localization.supportedLocales, (locale) => {
            let modifiedRoute = Object.assign({}, route);
            modifiedRoute.name = route.name + '___' + locale;
            localizedRoutes.push(modifiedRoute);
        });
    });

    router.addRoutes(localizedRoutes);

}
```

And the helpers to generate correct route name and route path are the following:

```
/**
 * Generate Backend Route
 * @param { string } path
 * @returns { string }
 */
export function backendRoute(path) {
    let basePath = application.backend_prefix.rtrim('/');
    let trimmedPath = path.ltrim('/');
    return basePath + '/' + trimmedPath;
}

/**
 * Generate route name compatible with nuxt
 * @param routeName
 * @returns {string}
 */
export function routeNameGenerator(routeName) {
    let parts = routeName.split('.');
    let backend = application.backend_prefix.replaceAll('/', '');
    return [].concat(...[backend], ...parts).join('-');
}
```

As i've already said, if you are navigating to the dynamically loaded route by actually following the path to the route, it will display the contents, but in case you want to access this route directly, 404 will be thrown but the breadcrumbs will still be generated as the route is kind of loaded, but at the same time it is not.

I've checked the output for the `this.$route` from the page inside the `/pages` directory and dynamic page, it is the same (not the paths and names obviously), so at this point i have no idea what is wrong with my way of loading routes.

Any help is really appreciated, and thank you for your time!

P.S. I'm not using `@nuxt\router` in favor of automatic route generation for files inside the `root\pages` directory.

**Update #1:**
Sometimes, it will occasionally throw the `Cannot read property 'layout' of undefined` error